# Custom email with firebase and angular

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I currently have firebase added to my angular 4 application and can successfully add the play and play email actions ( resetPassword, recoverEmail, verifyEmail ) by just hooking into angularfire2 with

```
.sendPasswordResetEmail(email); // etc
```

What i would like to do is take advantage of firebase and sent a custom email for a custom operation. So for example i want to "activate" a user which is done with custom code, when the administrator triggers the user active. When that happens i would like to send an email to that user and just use the firebase integration already there.

is it at all possible?

Comment: Cannot be done. Use a service like Mailgun.

Comment: mailgun looks good thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom emails ( for purposes that are not offered by Firebase out of the box such as password reset and email verification ), you'd have to use a third party email client like nodemailer or Sendgrid. This is quite easy to set up using Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation) from the official Cloud functions [samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples).

Please note, though, that you'd need to set up billing to access third party services from Cloud Functions.